# WP Create User - Preventing repeated information

Tags: users, email

I am using the

```
<?php wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email ); ?>
```

function in a contact form to create a subscriber when the user enters infomation on the contact form, thus in the background adding their email address to the database and giving them an account for site access.

Does this way of doing it though not mean that if a user sends 3 messages from the contact form they end up with 3 accounts with the same email address, or will it check to see if the email address or user name already exists.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `wp_create_user` calls `‪wp_insert_user‬` which check to see if `$username` and `$email` already exists and if so it returns a new WP_Error so you wont have duplicate users in your database and it wont send the new user email more then once, but i'm not sure if that is the best way to do that.

Comment: It will do for me

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid duplicate users by using `username_exists` function.

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
if ( username_exists( $username ) )
    echo "Username In Use!";
else
    echo "Username Not In Use!";
```